# Positioning axes labels

Tags: r, plot, axes

How can I move the y axis label from the left to the right of the plot area and the x-axis label from below to above the plot area in the following graph? Thanks

```
xleft<-c(1,2,2.5)
xright<-c(2,2.5,2.75)
ybottom<-c(1,2,2.5)
ytop<-c(2,2.5,2.75)

par(mar = c(15,15,2.75,2.75) + 0.1)
plot(c(1,3),c(1,3),type="n",main="title",xlab="xlab-move me above plot",ylab="ylab-move me      right of plot",axes=F,asp=1)
axis(1,pos=1)
axis(2,pos=1)


rect(xleft,ybottom,xright,ytop,col=c("blue","red","green"))

#Label position along  axes
x.label.position<-(xleft+xright)/2
y.label.position<-(ybottom+ytop)/2

#Labels
x.label<-c("Long species Name1","Long species Name2","Long species Name3")
y.label<-c("Long species Name4","Long species Name5","Long species Name5")

text(par()$usr[1]-0.5,y.label.position,y.label,xpd=TRUE,adj=1)
text(y=par()$usr[3]-0.5,x=x.label.position,x.label,xpd=TRUE,adj=1,srt=90)

par(xpd=TRUE)
legend(-0.1,0,legend=c("Species A","Species B","Species C"),fill=c("blue", "red", "green"))
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, this issue is exactly the reason of [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12300667/1451109) to your previous question.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean plannapus. How does changing the axes but not the plotting area cause problem for the x and y labels?

Comment: You just moved the axis, not the limit of your plot: your labels are at a given distance from the limits of your plot not from the axes (Type `box()` after your `axis` call, to make the limits of the plot appear and you'll see what I mean). It is not a big issue however since Backlin's solution makes it work nonetheless.

Comment: AhI see what you mean no. Thanks for the lesson :)

Answer (score 67):

### Ploting axes on the right and top sides of a plot

By default R will plot the x-axis below the plot area and the y-axis to the left of it. You can change this behaviour in this way:

```
plot(1:100, cumsum(rnorm(100)), type="l", axes=FALSE) # Do not plot any axes
axis(3)   # Draw the x-axis above the plot area
axis(4)   # Draw the y-axis to the right of the plot area
box()
```

[image]

To also move the labels you set `ann=FALSE` or `xlab="", ylab=""` and add them afterwards with `mtext`, where `side=1` is bottom, 2 is left, 3 is top, 4 is right. `line` controls the distance from the plot area.

```
plot(1:100, cumsum(rnorm(100)), type="l", axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)
axis(3)
box()
mtext("Top axis", side=3, line=3)
```

[image]

### Changing distance between labels, ticks and plot area.

Use the `mgp` parameter to control these details, either before the call to `plot`, like this

```
par(mgp=c(axis.title.position, axis.label.position, axis.line.position))
```

or in the `plot` command itself, like this

```
plot(1:100, cumsum(rnorm(100)), type="l", mgp=c(2,1,.5), las=1)
```

[image]

Also note the `las` parameter that turns all tick labels horisontal, which makes them easier to read.

Comment: Tackar tackar! That worked great although I had to use line=-1 to get it change sides. Is it possible to 'flip' the axis ticks and associated numbering in a similar way? I can post a new question if you feel this is a different question. Thanks again

Comment: The `las` parameter controls rotation of tick labels, `mtext` and various other text related things. Use `plot(..., las=1)` to make all tick labels horizontal. This is indeed a very good idea, it makes the graph much easier to read.

Comment: hmmm...sorry I think my question may have been unclear. I want to move the tick mark and number to above and to the right of the plot area. The las command is for just rotating text relative to the axis..I want to move the axes to the opposites side of the plot.

Comment: Oh, that I have no idea about. Never even seen an R plot like that.