# R Unequal spacing between axes and axes labels

Tags: r, plot

I would like to know why the distance between the axes and axes labels differs on both axes? How can this be fixed? Sample code and figure below.

```
png("test.png",height=7,width=7,units="cm",res=300)
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
par(mgp=c(1,0.2,0))
plot(x=1:10,y=1:10,axes=F,xlab="",ylab="")
box()
axis(side=1,cex.axis=0.5,tcl = -0.12)
axis(side=2,cex.axis=0.5,tcl = -0.12)
dev.off()
```

[image: figure]

Comment: possible duplicate of [moving axes labels in r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302366/moving-axes-labels-in-r)

Comment: @RHA certainly not a dupe of that one

Comment: the answer is in the answer, however

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the position of labels with the `padj` and `hadj` options:

```
axis(side=1,cex.axis=0.5,tcl = -0.12, padj=-1, hadj=0.5)
axis(side=2,cex.axis=0.5,tcl = -0.12, padj=0, hadj=0.5)
```