# R: how to move axes labels closer to the plot

Tags: r, visualization

I would like to move the axes labels closer to my plot. How can I do that?

```
set.seed(3)
plot(rnorm(10), xlab = "Age", ylab = "Weight", cex.lab = 1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Does the last part of the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302366/moving-axes-labels-in-r) help?

Comment: Thank you very much! By the way, is there a way to change the line thickness in the plot function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the command you're looking for is:

```
par(mgp=c(2,1,0))
```

Then create your plot:

```
plot(rnorm(10), xlab = "Age", ylab = "Weight", cex.lab = 1.5)
```

Once you're done you can reset it to the default:

```
par(mgp=c(3,1,0))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `title()` and specifying `line` should work for you. You may also want to consider changing the margins via `par(oma = c())` or `par(mar = c())` (the sequence of numbers goes: bottom, left, top, right).

```
set.seed(3)
plot(rnorm(10), xlab = "Age", ylab = "", cex.lab = 1.5)
title(ylab = "Weight", line = 2, cex.lab = 1.5)
```

Hope it helps