# How to place the intercept of x and y axes at (0 , 0) and extend the x and y axes to the edge of the plot

Tags: r, plot, curve, axes

Suppose I want to plot `x^2`. I can use `curve()` as follows.

```
curve(x^2, -5, 5)
```

[image]
However, I would like the axes to go through (0, 0). I could do something as follows:

```
curve(x^2, -5, 5, axes=FALSE)
axis(1, pos=0)
axis(2, pos=0)
abline(h=0)
abline(v=0)
```

And I end up getting something like below, which looks OK. But the only gripe I have is that this way of plotting axes makes the actual axes - for example the segment between -4 and 4 of the x-axis - thicker than the segments to the right side and the left side. The same goes with the y axis. I wonder if there is a better way of plotting the axes. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to make your plots look like the ones Excel produces?

Comment: @GavinSimpson: Ha! I actually didn't know Excel made plots that looked this way. Rarely use Excel for plotting purposes. For my data, the (0, 0) is important, so I thought letting the axes cross this point would make more sense.

Comment: The answer you checked is great; just thought I'd throw this option in: do the default plot, and then add identifier lines wherever you want them, e.g. `lines(c(0,0), c(-1,10),lty=4)` for a y-axis at x=0

Comment: @Alex IMHO I think the default R output is much better (no axis in the middle of the important data, tick labels not obscured by data or other axes, ...). If (0,0) is important, I would just add a lightgrey line using `abline(v = 0)` and `abline(h = 0)` calls, preferably in the background.

Comment: @gavin -- sounds like what I wrote :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default, axis() computes automatically the tick marks position, but you can define them manually with the `at` argument. So a workaround could be something like :

```
curve(x^2, -5, 5, axes=FALSE)
axis(1, pos=0, at=-5:5)
axis(2, pos=0)
```

Which gives :

[image]

The problem is that you have to manually determine the position of each tick mark. A slightly better solution would be to compute them with the `axTicks` function (the one used by default) but calling this one with a custom `axp` argument which allows you to specify respectively the minimum, maximum and number of intervals for the ticks in the axis :

```
curve(x^2, -5, 5, axes=FALSE)
axis(1, pos=0, at=axTicks(1,axp=c(-10,10,10)))
axis(2, pos=0)
```

Which gives :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The arguments `yaxs` and `xaxs` control spacing around plots. Set to `"i"` to omit this:

```
curve(x^2, -5, 5, yaxs = "i")
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12300673/567015

Comment: This option trims at both ends, not just at (0,0) with bad side-effects for some plots, e.g. plot with a lot of data points spread flat near the top, as with a bell-shaped curve. Also, for some reasons, the axis will overwrite the dots/lines, making data near the ends hard to see.