# How to generate x,y plot starting from 0 in R?

Tags: r, plot

This refers to my previous question.

[Line plot of multiple variables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17562379/how-to-plot-mulitple-line-plots-in-r/17562733#17562733)

But graph always start from value less than 0 while in excel it is ok.

Excel plot:

[image]

R plot:

[image]

How can i start the axes at (0,0) only in R?

Comment: you should have a look to the paramaters of the par function. par(xaxs="i") should do the work, for the y axis it is yaxs="i".

Comment: You claim that "in excel it is ok" is dubious. The graph using default settings in R looks much better.

Comment: I updated my answer to the previous question to address this issue before I saw this question. I can give the same answer again here, but I'm not sure that's best; there is no longer anything distinctive to this question.